# Probability of a 7 card sequence (same suit) in a 32 card game

Tags: probability

Deck of **four suits** of 8 cards each (**32 cards total**). **Two Players** with 12 cards each.

The probability of **8 sequential cards** is supposably:
$$\binom{4}{1} \times \frac{\binom{8}{8}\binom{24}{4}}{\binom{32}{12}} $$

What is the probability of getting **7 sequential cards**? Is it:
$$ 2 \times \binom{4}{1} \times \frac{\binom{8}{7}\binom{1}{0}\binom{23}{5}}{\binom{32}{12}} $$

Comment: Same color, or same suit?  (Diamonds and hearts are different suits with the same color.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The probability of **8 sequential cards** is supposably:
>   $$\binom{4}{1} \times \frac{\binom{8}{8}\binom{24}{4}}{\binom{32}{12}} $$

This is misleading you.   It is correct for the wrong reasons and that is throwing you off.

You have a deck of four suits of 8 cards each (32 cards total).   (PS: You should mention this at the start; you *really* should.)

Two players are dealt twelve cards.   The probability that *one particular player* draws a straight sequence of 8 cards of one suit is: $$\dfrac{\dbinom 41\dbinom {24} 4}{\dbinom{32}{12}}$$

Where we are counting: $\tbinom 4 1$ ways to select one of four suits for the eight cards and $\tbinom{24}{4}$ ways to select any four cards of any of the other suits, divided by the $\tbinom{32}{12}$ ways to select any 12 cards in the deck.

We *don't* actually count $\tbinom 8 8$ ways to select eight cards from eight cards in a suit.   Rather we count the $1$ way to select a straight of eight from a suit.   This has the same *numerical* value, but the logic behind the representation is in error.

---

So the probability that *one particular player draws* a straight of 7 cards from one suit is:

$$\dfrac{\dbinom 21~\dbinom 41 \dbinom {24} 5 - \dbinom{4}{1}\dbinom{24}{4}}{\dbinom{32}{12}}$$

As there are only *two ways* to draw a straight of seven cards from a suit of eight (by selecting the lowest card of the straight from a possibility of two).   *However* we must avoid over-counting the intersection — of drawing both possibilities by drawing a straight of eight — hence the *subtracted* term.   (The *Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion* should be familiar to you; if not, make it so.)

---

If you move on to calculating the probability that *one particular player* draws a straight of *six*, you also have to consider the possibility of drawing them in two suits.   (Because: twelve card hand.)

---

Also, these are the probabilities for draws by *one particular player*.   The probability that either one of the two players draws a straight of eight is:

$$\dfrac{\dbinom {2}{1}~\dbinom{4}{1}\dbinom{24}{4}\dbinom{20}{12}-\dbinom 4 1\dbinom{24}{4}\dbinom 3 1\dbinom{12}{4}}{\dbinom{32}{12}\dbinom{20}{12}}$$

Can you see what is being counted, and *why*?   Thence can you calculate the probability that *either player draws a straight of seven cards*?

Comment: Yes.  Typo @Passi

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you rationale for the ${1\choose 0}$ in the equation.  But since ${1\choose 0} = 1$ it has no influence.

the ${8\choose 7}$ is creating possibilities that don't apply.

If you have 7 cards in sequence (with 8 to choose from) there are only two possible sequence you might have.  (which is the 2 in the front of your equation)
but the ${8\choose 7} = 8$ is a suggestion that you have any 7 of the 8 cards in that color, which is not the case.

$\dfrac {{4\choose1}(2){24\choose 5}}{{32\choose 12}}$

Comment: I'm so sorry. I meant $$ 2 \times \binom{4}{1} \times \frac{\binom{8}{7}\binom{1}{0}\binom{23}{5}}{\binom{32}{12}} $$ 
If I have 7 sequential cards, the 8th card of this sequence shouldn't be among the remaining cards. Like so: $$ \binom{1}{0}\binom{23}{5} $$
The assumption, that the remaining cards are random, implies, that this 8th card could be among the remaining cards. Or is this consideration wrong?

Comment: @Passi, there are 24 remaining cards, $32-8$ where 32 is the number of total cards and 8 is the number of cards from one suit, in this case the suit the sequence is from. Also, you didn't take into account that there are two players. If you are asking the probability that (at least) one of the players has a sequence, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are four suits, with 8 cards each.

If one player has 12 cards out of those 32, then the probability is indeed 
$\frac{\color{red}{4\cdot 1 } \cdot \color{green}{ \binom{24}{4}} }{\color{blue}{\binom{32}{12}}}$, where $\color{red}{4\cdot 1}$ is the number of ways to choose a sequence of 8 colors, $\color{green}{ \binom{24}{4}}$ the number of ways to choose the remaining cards and $\color{blue}{\binom{32}{12}}$ the total number of ways to draw 12 cards.

---

However, if we take into account that there two players, the probability becomes:

$$\large{\frac{\color{red}{4\cdot 1 } \cdot \color{green}{ \binom{24}{4}} \cdot \color{green}{ \binom{20}{12}} \, + \color{red}{4\cdot 1 } \cdot \color{green}{ \binom{24}{4}} \cdot \color{green}{ \binom{20}{12}} \, - \color{red}{12\cdot 1 } \cdot \color{green}{ \binom{16}{4}} \cdot \color{green}{ \binom{12}{4}}  }{\color{blue}{\binom{32}{12}\binom{20}{12}}}}$$

where $\large{\color{red}{4\cdot 1}}$ is the number of ways to choose a sequence of 8 colors, which is $\large{\color{red}{12\cdot 1}}$ for the probability that both have a 8 card sequence (4&3 possibilities for the suits), $\color{green}{ \binom{24}{4}\binom{20}{12}} $ the number of ways to choose the remaining cards  for one of the players and all cards for the other player, and $\color{blue}{\binom{32}{12}\binom{20}{12}}$ the total number of ways to draw 12 cards for two players. We substract the probability that both players have a sequence of length 8.

---

As Doug M pointed out, you made a small mistake in the seven card case. He explains the one player case, so here is the two player case:

$$\large{\frac{\color{red}{4\cdot 2 } \cdot \color{green}{ \binom{24}{5}} \cdot \color{green}{ \binom{21}{12}} \, + \color{red}{4\cdot 2 } \cdot \color{green}{ \binom{24}{5}} \cdot \color{green}{ \binom{21}{12}} \, - \color{red}{12\cdot 4 } \cdot \color{green}{ \binom{16}{5}} \cdot \color{green}{ \binom{11}{5}}  }{\color{blue}{\binom{32}{12}\binom{20}{12}}}}$$

Here, the red, green an blue numbers play the same role.

So $\large{\color{red}{4\cdot 2}}$ is the number of ways to choose a sequence of 7 colors, which is $\large{\color{red}{12\cdot 4}}$ for the probability that both have a 7 card sequence (4&3 possibilities for the suits times 2 times 2 because they are sequential), $\color{green}{ \binom{24}{4}\binom{20}{12}} $ the number of ways to choose the remaining cards  for one of the players and all cards for the other player, and $\color{blue}{\binom{32}{12}\binom{20}{12}}$ the total number of ways to draw 12 cards for two players. We substract the probability that both players have a sequence of length 7.